# Prevent users from downloading files in a specific directory

Tags: php, file

My website is coded using PHP.
Library files are stored in a directory called 'library'.

Within my php I access the library files by

```
require_once('library/myfile.php.inc');
```

However, if the user types in

http://www.example.com/library/myfile.php.inc

They are able to download the source code.
How can I prevent this?

Comment: Set chmod to allow access to files only for group and owner

Comment: `.htaccess` rules would cover that scenario.

Comment: omit the '.inc' (it's not 2004 anymore) or configure your webserver to handle the file extension properly (e.g. htaccess).

Comment: Alternatively, you can call them `*.inc.php` (or better, just `*.php`) and check within the file if it's included or called directly.

Comment: It's also usually sensible to call your includes myfile.inc.php, and then wrap <?php ?> tags around them - that way, the file is parsed as PHP on the server, so the source code is never sent to the browser.... note that this isn't 100% guaranteed (as any procedural code in your file will still be processed), but is better than not doing it, and is perfect for Class files, which won't be run at all without any procedural code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create .htaccess file under root/library/.htaccess
and write the following

```
<FilesMatch ".*">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from All
</FilesMatch>
```